# What are the types of Python operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried `type(+)` hoping to know more about how is this operator represented in python but i got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
My main problem is to cast as string representing an operation :"3+4" into the real operation to be computed in Python (so to have an int as a return: 7).
I am also trying to avoid easy solutions requiring the os library if possible.

Comment: Could you be more clear with what are you trying to achieve? The question seems too broad.

Comment: I'm reluctant to mention it, but `eval()` is the conventional way to execute a string as if it was code. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html before deciding whether it is appropriate for you.

Comment: One good start point to know more about operators is the [```operator```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

Comment: yes eval() is a good start thanks for the documentation.

Comment: My main purpuse is too read an operation involving addition , multiplication, etc, written in a string and to return the operation computed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operators don't really have types, as they aren't values. They are just syntax whose implementation is often defined by a magic method (e.g., `+` is defined by the appropriate type's `__add__` method).

You have to *parse* your string:

1. First, break it down into *tokens*: `['3', '+', '4']`
2. Then, parse the token string into an abstract syntax tree (i.e., something at stores the idea of `+` having `3` and `4` as its operands).
3. Finally, *evaluate* the AST by applying functions stored at a node to the values stored in its children.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html for more relevant info.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `eval` function probably does what you want:

```
eval('3+4')
```

returns `7`.